# TS2345: Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.3

Weird error with TypeScript:

[image]

As the image indicates, the error is:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'ErrnoException' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(err: ErrnoException) => void'. Type
>   'ErrnoException' provides no match for the signature '(err:
>   ErrnoException): void'.

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
export const bump = function(cb: ErrnoException){
  const {pkg, pkgPath} = syncSetup();
  fs.writeFile(pkgPath, JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2), cb);
};
```

Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a value with the type **ErrnoException**, while the function you are calling expects a function that takes a parameter of type *ErrnoException** and returns void.

You send:

```
let x = new ErrnoException;
```

While the function you call expects

```
let cb = function(e: ErrnoException) {};
```

You can change your function to receive the correct parameter like this.

```js
export const bump = function(cb: (err: ErrnoException) => void){
  const {pkg, pkgPath} = syncSetup();
  fs.writeFile(pkgPath, JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2), cb);
};
```